# Authenticate cloud function with firebase authentication

Tags: firebase, authentication, google-cloud-functions, cloud

I have the code to authenticate the cloud function http trigger with firebase token, but it needs to get the token from header and check the validity of token through firebase admin...

comparing similar approach with AWS.

We don't need to do the coding to authenticate the Lambda function, while deploying we can only need to configure the correct coginto pool as authorizer and AWS do the rest..

I was looking for same thing in google cloud, but couldn't found this...

can anyone suggest is this approach possible with  gcp.

Thanks,

Comment: I guess yiu are speaking about this sample: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/main/Node-1st-gen/authorized-https-endpoint. It is just a matter of some few lines of code. AFAIK there isn't any alternative way to do that.

Comment: I have the link you given, but as I said, we need to write the code, but if you compare with aws you don't need to write the code, I am expecting it should be there as both ther services firebase authentication and cloud function both are of gcp, as cognito and lambda are both of aws

Comment: So the answer is (AFAIK): for the moment you need to code it.